# Aside from a table of textboxes, how can I ask for a user's weekly schedule?

Tags: php, html

Aside from creating a table of textboxes that asks the user to enter their class for each hour, how else can I ask them? I feel like it's a lot of work typing in course codes for each timeslot that they have class. I only used plain HTML in this project, but I'm open to learning  other technologies if it would make the user's job easier (and if learning the technology is easy too).

```
TIME     MON       TUE      WED       THU       FRI
7-8     txtbx1   txtbx2   txtbx3     txtbx4    txtbx5
```

Comment: An acquaintance of mine built [this schedule builder](http://bitman.freeshell.org/schedulebuilder.php) eons ago, but he provided the source code. It may help you some.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the class codes available, i would suggest binding the textbx to a drop down list consisting of all the classes, then the user just clicks on the class and it auto fills in the textbox, but with this i would suggest using javascript or better yet jQuery library

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I forgot to include this in the question: creating a dropdown of class codes would be inconvenient because that would be a hundred or more class codes.

Comment: well you can always calculate which classes are offered in that time slot, or which classes the user has signed up for, there must be a filter in some or other way

Comment: The project I'm creating doesn't depend or isn't connected to any of the university's data - I'm merely tasked to create a scheduler for student employees. Too bad I don't have data for each subject's schedule or something to that extent..

Comment: Hm, well if the user has to enter then trust me, there will be alot of mistakes made, it doesn't have to be a drop down, you can display a division just overlaying the normal page having all the classes where he can search an click on the class, but i dont think the txtbx's should be editable, then you can be sure then the info you get back would be valid

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take an orthogonal approach: The user doesn't **think** of his week as a matrix of hours, some of them filled with courses. He thinks of his week as a list of courses.

Mirroring this, you could simply ask to input a list of courses, with course codes (either also have him input the times or if possible resolve the times from the course codes), then create the matrix by simple calculation.

Comment: I'm thinking it will be complicated because for each subject input, I have to a) get the day(s) this class takes place and b) get the exact time, because I don't have access to the university's data for this kinds of things.